# Grouping in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

Sorry for this newbie question.

I have 1 SQL Server table:

```
            Column1 | Column2 | Column3
Row1           A         1         100
Row2           A         1         200
Row3           A         2          50
Row4           B         4          10
Row5           C         5          20
```

Here in this report i would like to get the output as:

```
            Column1 | Column2 | Colum3
Row1           A         1        300
Row2           A         2         50
Row3           B         4         10
Row4           C         5         20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert group on Column1
2. Insert group on Column2
3. Suppress all sections except group #2 header
4. Place Column1, Column2, and Sum(Column3) into the group #2 header